# JavasScript RegEx Replace Pattern in String that Looks Like An Array

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array in string-format. With Javascript, how to replace `[`, `]`, `<Tag:` , and `>` in the least amount of code possible:

```
let s = "[<Tag: cats>, <Tag: dogs>, <Tag: parakeets>]"
```

End result should look like:

```
"cats, dogs, parakeets"
```

This seems to work, but it's pretty... not great.

```
s.replace(/^\[/, '').replace(/\]$/, '').replaceAll('<Tag: ', '').replaceAll('>', '')
```

Is there a clever way to do this with RegEx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching `<Tag:`  and then capturing non-`>` characters looks like it'd do what you want:

```js
const s = "[<Tag: cats>, <Tag: dogs>, <Tag: parakeets>]";
const result = s.replace(/<Tag: ([^>]+)>/g, '$1').replace(/[[\]]/g, '');
console.log(result);
```

Another approach, matching instead of replacing:

```js
const s = "[<Tag: cats>, <Tag: dogs>, <Tag: parakeets>]";
const result = [...s.matchAll(/<Tag: ([^>]+)>/g)]
  .map(match => match[1])
  .join(', ');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: How about using `(.+?)` instead of `([^>]+)`?

Comment: Lazy repetition, while it looks nicer, is less efficient than a negative character set

Comment: I just ran a benchmark: `html.matchAll(/<[^>]+>/g)` vs. `html.matchAll(/<.+?>/g)` on this page's HTML source code and the latter one was faster by 6.5%.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest matching all substrings and joining them:

```js
const result = [...s.matchAll(/<Tag:\s*(\w+)>/g)]
    .map(
        ([, m]) => m
    )
    .join(', ');


// result: "cats, dogs, parakeets"
```

Comment: Slight issue. If tag is multi-word (ex: `<Tag: something with spaces>`) the regex needs to allow for spaces. I failed to provide an example in my initial question. I think `([\w\s]+)` will work.

Comment: @Jarad yes, if you need spaces then what you suggested will work :)

Answer (score 1):

When an infinite quantifier in a lookbehind is [supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind), you can match all the values between `<Tag:`  and the `>` and make sure all the matches are between square brackets.

See the regex matches in this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VuMbI9/1).

```js
let s = "[<Tag: cats>, <Tag: dogs>, <Tag: parakeets>]"
const regex = /(?<=\[[^\][]*<Tag: )\w+(?=>[^\][]*\])/g;
console.log(s.match(regex).join(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Remove the delimiters `[`, `]`, `>` and `<Tag:`  parts:

```js
let s = "[<Tag: cats>, <Tag: dogs>, <Tag: parakeets>]";
s = s.replace(/[[\]>]|<.*? /g, "");
console.log(s);
```

Comment: FYI: I didn't downvote. Your answer seems to work on my simple string. I too would like to know what might be wrong with your answer. It is probably the shortest.

Comment: I didn't downvote neither, but even though your answer will work in this case, when designing a pattern for regex, you should avoid false positives. It's just not the greatest pattern, may lead to unstable results.

Comment: Not my downvote, but there is imho no reason to use "<.*? " instead of "<Tag: ". This disallows spaces and brackets in the text, uses a ".*?" (which should be considerably more work than necessary, albeit this difference usually being irrelevant), and is harder to read and grasp the intention from, at least imho.

Comment: Some other answers create intermediate arrays... or perform two `replace` calls, and they get upvoted. I'm lost.

Comment: @trincot but they are more readable than yours.

Comment: Sure, but the question was *"in the least amount of code possible"*... so... I probably should skip such questions in the future :/

Answer (score 0):

Not using a regex but it does return the same result that need.

```
let res = ""
let s = "[<Tag: cats>, <Tag: dogs>, <Tag: parakeets>]"

for ( let i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
  let c = s[i]
  if ( c == '[' || c == ']' || c == '>')
    continue
  else if ( s.substr(i,5) == '<Tag:')
    i += 5
  else
    res += c
}
return res
```